# Rename table with spaces mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'A B C' (with spaces, don't ask me why) in MySQL database. 
I have to rename it to 'ABC' 
This query doesn't work :(

```
rename table 'A B C' to 'ABC'
```

What should be the correct query?

I get the same usual error

```
'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Escape the name with backticks.

```
rename table `A B C` to ABC
```

Comment: Thanks.. That works... Why didn't (') work. I thought (') is the general syntax of enclosing.

Comment: No. Backticks are used in MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Use backticks:

```
rename table `A B C` to ABC;
```

Comment: Thanks.. That works... Why didn't (') work. I thought (') is the general syntax of enclosing.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to enclose the name w/spaces with tick marks (`) instead of single (') quotes. I don't know how to escape ticks so they show in the code preview but I think you will be able to figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the sql query there and copy the nme of the table, after that paste back it in the query and enter your new name

Example : RENAME TABLE 'sales record' to sales

the 'sales record' need to copy from the sql original query there