# I can't rename a mysql table name... it has a space in it

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, ddl, table-rename

I've imported a csv into MySQL. PHPMyAdmin helpfully created a table called TABLE 8 (with a space).

When I try to rename in SQL:

```
RENAME TABLE 8 to gender
```

I get the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`TABLE 8` to `gender`' at line 1
```

I have tried back-ticks, quotes... seemingly everything...

I guess it's the space that's causing the problem but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What's the name of the table `table 8`?  `Rename table 'table 8' to 'gender'` where ticks are backticks

Comment: Yes, TABLE 8 @xQbert

Comment: Thanks @xQbert - got it. Cheers. :-)

Comment: Yep worked for me on sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d989c/1/0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename table with spaces mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522708/rename-table-with-spaces-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using backticks around field names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names)

Comment: @Jocelyn oh yeah well then I will find a 4th one :p

Comment: TBH it was an omission on the keyword TABLE not a back tick issue... so give me a break! ;-) (It's bad enough that I miss it in the first place!)

Comment: @stilts77 All programmers make mistakes, sometimes very simple ones!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is wrong, you're missing the `table` keyword (and yes, note the `s to escape the table name containing a space):

```
RENAME TABLE `TABLE 8` TO gender
```

Alternatively, you could use the fuller syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE `TABLE 8` RENAME TO gender
```